# Auto generate primary key as current date time in H2 database

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, primary-key, h2

I have to create a table in `H2` with primary key in `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` format.So that for every insert it automatically takes current date time in the mentioned format.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(ID BIGINT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(255));
```

Problem is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.How can I get it in required format.

Comment: I changed one tag to SQL in order to have the proper syntax highlighting in both your question and my answer. Hope the answer helped solving your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in the H2 console:

```
call formatdatetime(now(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS');
```

This will give you a properly formatted string. Now you need to convert it to bigint.

```
call cast(formatdatetime(now(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS') as bigint);
```

Last step: change your SQL accordingly...

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(
  ID BIGINT DEFAULT CAST(FORMATDATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS') AS BIGINT) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Tested on H2 1.3 and 1.4.

**Word of caution:** please use transactions and space your insertions...

Comment: This worked for me, Sorry for replying late.I executed the 3td sql directly, why do I need the first 2 sqls? just to verify is it?

Comment: @livinggourmand yes the first two were just there to educate through experimentation. Good to know the full 3rd SQL helped you